# Method to request reexamination of patent for instructional video

Tags: uspto, reexamination, obviousness, us8605152

I am in the process of filing a reexamination request for patent [8,605,152](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=8,605,152.PN.&OS=PN/8,605,152&RS=PN/8,605,152): Method and apparatus for yoga class imaging and streaming.

Under what grounds would I challenge a patent for an instructional video?

Comment: A reexamination request has a filing fee of $6000, assuming you qualify as a small entity. I would highly recommend getting professional assistance to insure it was well spent.

Comment: Also look into micro entity fees. That could be as low as $3,000.

Comment: There is an asterisk on that $3000. It is not available for third parties, only for the patentee themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grounds for an exparte reexamination are restricted to novelty and obvious challenges based on patents or published documents and on section 112 issues. Section 112 includes the requirement for proper support for claims in the specification, the claims not being indeterminate, and the specification being enabling.

The allowed grounds do *not* include section 101 which sets out subject matter requirements. Claim 1 of this patent seems to positively require *students*, who, I presume are human. It may seem silly, but this is "patenting humans" and is not allowed under previous policy and was codified in the AIA.